# What's the longest scheduled flight one can take within the EU?

Tags: air-travel, eu, factoids

Not counting [Special member state territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_state_territories_and_the_European_Union) what's the longest scheduled flight one can take starting and ending in an EU airport?

Comment: So you're discounting the Azores because "derogations from the application of EU law could apply" even though "none do"?

Comment: Ivalo to Flores?

Comment: @CountIblis Flores is part of a "special member state territory" so out of scope of the question.

Comment: @phoog I see! [What about this flight?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlS_FLwcAN8)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Air Berlin flight from Düsseldorf to Düsseldorf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlS_FLwcAN8) is a 12 hour sightseeing flight covering a distance of 9780 km.

Comment: +1. I **tried** to think of a reason why this doesn't answer the question,  but I failed. It's *scheduled* (their official website talks about the next *scheduled* flight.) Also,  you can't disqualify it because it leaves EU territory.  That would also disqualify all flights crossing Swiss/Norwegian/Liechtensteinian airspace. Also,  OP doesn't say "longest distance between airports"  he just says "longest flight". I have to admit that this meets all of OP's criteria,  and it easily wins by distance traveled.

Comment: It's a great answer. It appears that the flight is really a Polarflug charter flight, operated by airberlin, which would really make it not a "regularly scheduled flight," but the question only asks about a "scheduled flight."

Comment: Must be quite a bummer to buy a ticket for a _sightseeing_ flight and not get a window seat -- but the video clearly shows the middle seats occupied too.  It seems to be doubtful whether any single-aisle airliner would have enough range to fly that trip without refueling stops, but still ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm They use an A330 and middle seats are significantly cheaper. Those sitting in the middle are also allowed to lean over the window passenger when flying by something interesting.

Comment: while it's a great answer, **length** of airline flights simply means the (great-circle) distance from point A to point B. it does not include (say) go-arounds, routing along corridors etc.  Again while this is a clever and great answer the OP is likely seeking - quite simply - the longest A-B distance.  Here, it is zero.

Comment: "I tried to think of a reason why this doesn't answer the question, but I failed".  Couldn't be simpler.  "Length" of airline flight means the distance from the take off site to the landing site.  Here, it is zero.

Comment: How can this be economical? Surely they cannot expect to fill seats that are not at least two seat from the window.

Comment: The question didn't specify whether it was longest distance or longest time.

Comment: @dan-klasson Then just charge twice as much for the window seats ?

Comment: @dan-klasson: "Economical" is simply a matter of being able to charge enough for the seats you _can_ fill.

Comment: To the question of window seats: I remember reading about the Antarctica equivalent of this flight (departing from Australia), they had a complicated seat-switching arrangement at specific times to ensure that everyone got some time by the window. I am surprised that this flight doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Air Berlin ceased operations in October 2017 so this flight is not scheduled anymore.

Answer (score 17):

### Larnaca, Cyprus to Dublin, Ireland

Flight distance is 2316 miles (3727 km) and flight time of **5h 35m** (via [Cobalt Air](https://www.dublinairport.com/latest-news/detail/dublin-airport-welcomes-new-twice-weekly-service-to-cyprus)seasonal route).

Cyprus is the easternmost country in the EU and this is the farthest flight available from it. If there was a scheduled flight to Lisbon it's be slightly better but not by much.
Going from east-west is better than south-north due to going against the prevailing winds so it takes longer.

[Flight distance](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LCA-DUB)

Answer (score 7):

Helsinki to Lisbon on Finnair (Flight TAP Portugal 791) takes **4h55m** and spans [just over 3350 kilometers](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=HEL-LIS).

It's unlikely anything else could come close, unless there are charter flights from the northernmost Finnish airports.

Comment: Tenerife is in a "special member state territory" so out of scope of the question.

Comment: @phoog I've thought it's not since it's in the Schengen. Answer updated.

Comment: I would include it on that basis, as well as the Azores, but I assume since chx linked to the Wikipedia article that mention in the article is definitive grounds for exclusion.

Comment: Flights from the northernmost Finnish airports: Well, there is a flight Rovaniemi–Chania (even though that is about 1000 km shorter) so the possibility exists.

Comment: Helsinki to Lisbon is 4:55

Comment: Is it Finnair (AY) or TAP Portugal (TP)? If on AY this is nice since, being over 2000 miles, it would earn a tidy 140 tier points in the BA airmiles scheme.

Comment: Also in terms of coming close, AY flies HEL-AGP (AY 733) which is six miles shorter. :)

Comment: This would seem to be the best answer, good one!

Comment: Zürich (ZRH) to Svalbard, Longyear (LYR) is 3439 kilometers: http://www.airmilescalculator.com/distance/zrh-to-lyr/ - there seems to be a [seasonal charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svalbard_Airport,_Longyear#Passenger).

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy too bad neither airport is in the EU.

Answer (score 4):

Following up hippietrail's suggestion:

**[ORY (Orly, Paris, France) to CAY (Cayenne, Guyane, France)](https://www.orbitz.com/Flights-Search?trip=oneway&leg1=from:Paris,%20France%20(PAR-All%20Airports),to:Cayenne,%20French%20Guiana%20(CAY-Rochambeau),departure:10/19/2016TANYT&passengers=adults:1,children:0,seniors:0,infantinlap:Y&options=cabinclass%3Aeconomy&mode=search&origref=www.orbitz.com)**

is 4420 miles, 7114 km, about 9 hr

Comment: If French Guiana counts, then I think Réunion should too, and RUN-CDG is 9349 km, 11h15 with Air Austral.

Comment: I know of Reunion and that's what I wanted to exclude, come now.

Comment: @chx: What does Réunion lack that French Guiana has?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: He wanted to exclude all overseas territory, otherwise a flight toward French Polynesia or New Caledonia would take you to the other end of the Earth (actually, there may not even be a direct flight, given how long the journey is).

Comment: while admirably clever, it does not seem to answer the sense of the OP's question.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Then I repeat: Why does the same criticism not apply to Ross's suggestion of French Guiana too?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: It does apply, and Ross' answer is "out" :)

Comment: While this answer might be wrong, it is not low quality nor in need of being removed, unless @Ross feels that need himself. Downvote if you do not like it, or just leave it alone as I chose to do.